# Find all words including those with special characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have texts in an excel file that looks something like this:

```
alpha123_4rf
45beta_Frank
Red5Great_Sam_Fun
dan.dan_mmem_ber
huh_k
han.jk_jj
huhu
```

I am trying to use a regex to match all of these words and save them into a `set()`.

I have tried `r"(\w+..*?_.*?\w+)"` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/vT4sQ3/56) . But cant seem to capture the word `huhu` that does not have special characters.

Comment: Why do you even try to match anything with a regex if you want all of them??

Comment: How'd you come up with that regex? What do you consider a word to be? Can you give examples of things you *don't* want to match?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is capturing word that have a `_` in them, and `huhu` don't. 
You could change your regex to match every letter, number, underscore, and dots, multiple times.

```
([\w.]+)
```

[I've fork your regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZI8EkR/1)

If you wish to match something more precise, you might need to give us more information about your context and what exactly you are trying to match.